# Conditional ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query. Something like this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    item,
    action,
    desc,
    time
FROM t1
WHERE bus = 6
ORDER BY action DESC, time ASC
```

I need to modify ORDER BY part and only use **action DESC** if **desc == ''**

Basically it will output results and sort them by time in ASC order and if there are any actions that do not have description will be pegged at the top. Is it possible to do in a single query? If yes, how do I incorporate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `case` statement is super-useful and lets you do all sorts of fun things.  Works everywhere a single column works.

```
SELECT
    id,
    item,
    action,
    t1.`desc`,
    time
FROM t1
WHERE bus = 6
ORDER BY 
  case t1.`desc` when '' then action else '' end DESC, 
  time ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Single query with one fake sort field.

```
SELECT
    `id`,
    `item`,
    `action`,
    `desc`,
    `time`
FROM t1
WHERE `bus` = 6
ORDER BY IF(`desc` = '', 0, 1), `action` DESC, `time` ASC
```

EDIT: Noticed that OP sql contains reserved word and I repeated it in my answer by assuming it is just sample - my bad. I added the backticks for future readers.