# Order by with where IN operator

Tags: mysql

How to make a query to mysql database to sort the results in descending order with condition that if a particular item present in list comes first.
For example I have a table of some post 'post_feeds' article which is mapped with category in category map table 'post_category_mapping'. I try to retrieve all posts from table 'post_feeds' in sorted order but with condition that if category_id present in list come first.

I try to do this by this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_category_mapping.post_id,
                posts_feeds.post_title
FROM post_category_mapping
INNER JOIN posts_feeds
    ON post_category_mapping.post_id = posts_feeds.post_id
ORDER BY CASE WHEN post_category_mapping.category_id IN (1,6)
              THEN posts_feeds.id END DESC,
         posts_feeds.id DESC"
```

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109084/conditional-order-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query is close.  To make the `CASE` trick work when ordering, you can assign a `0` for matching category IDs, and a `1` for non matching IDs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.post_id,
                t2.post_title
FROM post_category_mapping t1
INNER JOIN posts_feeds t2
    ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t1.category_id IN (1,6) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         t2.id DESC
```

This would place all records having a `category_id` of 1 or 6 before all records not having these values.  And within each matching/non matching block, the records would be ordered descending by `posts_feed.id`.